# What are "hangers" in the context of American Revolution duel?

Tags: meaning

I was reading in wikipedia about Hessian auxiliaries (AKA mercenaries) used by the British during the American Revolution and I read this account:

> The chaplain then recounts the case of a Jaeger subaltern who was assailed "by an Englishman in his cups" with the declaration: "God damn you, Frenchy, you take our pay!" The outraged Hessian replied: "I am a German and you are a shit." This was followed by an impromptu duel with hangers, in which the Englishman received a fatal wound.

[Hessian (soldier)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_(soldier))

What are "hangers"?

Comment: @user66974 That's an answer. You can vote and vote-to-close for research as well. Please don't *just* answer in a comment.

Comment: @Andew Leach I did research but the results for (duel hangers) were overwhelming in "closet" and "airplane" responses. I do admit I gave a look at the first couple of pages of results and gave up.

Comment: https://www.thehemashop.com/american-revolutionary-hanger

Comment: @Jim I imagine that most of the "airplane" responses were spelled "hangar".

Comment: @MarcInManhattan good catch! I saw *one* with hanger spelling (and that was a a jedi sword fight in a "hanger") and my brain went with "planes many". Still, with "hanger|hangar", nothing about short swords.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hanger) has:

> : *Obsolete*
> a short sword hung from the belt

and

> a light saber of the 17th and 18th centuries, often worn by sailors

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutlass) for [cutlass](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cutlass):

> In England about 1685 the rather long straight-bladed sword formerly in use began to be superseded by the "hanger". This weapon had a short and more or less curved single-edged blade with a brass hilt of a rather flat double-shell and knuckle-bow. The grip was generally of wood, bound with wire, but some specimens show a brass grip with spiral grooves. These are probably early models. The length of the blade is usually about 24 inches.

From Richard Iorio and Daniel D. Fox's [*FLAMES OF FREEDOM Grim & Perilous RPG*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=BVQ5EAAAQBAJ&pg=PA184&lpg=PA184&dq=what+were+%22hanger%22s+used+to+fight+in+a+war&source=bl&ots=t9ybOlCJr0&sig=ACfU3U13aL69jSX5xVwZHKq9jfTPik6FCg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjP5MuPnaj3AhUOGqYKHemBCk8Q6AF6BAgmEAM#v=onepage&q=what%20were%20%22hanger%22s%20used%20to%20fight%20in%20a%20war&f=false):

> HANGER SWORD: Shoddy and more for show than any real fighting, hanger swords are used in duels for reputation.

From [Wikipedia: *Classification of swords*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_swords):

> The hanger (Obs. *whinyard, whinger, cuttoe*), wood-knife or hunting sword is a long knife or short sword that hangs from the belt and was popular as both a hunting tool and weapon of war.

From [americanrevolutioninstitute.org](https://www.americanrevolutioninstitute.org/recent-acquisitions/minute-man-sword/):

> During the Revolutionary War, infantrymen carried a hanger—a type of short sword, with a blade about twenty-five inches long—as a secondary weapon to supplement their musket in close combat.

Comment: your search-fu is awesome.

Comment: Should we be doing basic research for our target audience (linguists/seasoned Anglophiles)? I'll not DV (though I've CVd) as your American Revolution Institute.org quote adds good detail.

Comment: Now, I know why some Brits went around saying, Hang it, man [good joke, based on your answer.]

Comment: Yes, if a linguist/seasoned Anglophile doesn't know the word, the word is obviously not worth knowing.